# Slope-one Recommendor

Tags: hadoop, mahout, mahout-recommender

I cloned Mahout with tag 0.7 from Github and trying to  run Slope one-Recommendendation util which is provided by Mahout to be run on Mahout . But I couldn't find any  such util. Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below class for Slope One Recommender:

org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.slopeone.SlopeOneRecommender

You can instantiate same by passing input data in form of DataModel object.

DataModel dataModel = new FileDataModel(new File("my_user_item_rating.csv");

Recommender recommender = new SlopeOneRecommender(dataModel);

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it a Hadoop based distributed version ?

Comment: Hadoop is not needed, as we are reading file from local filesystem.